# TableView not adding all the information into a table

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

So we have a tableview in our Javafx GUI and we are trying to add certain information into the columns, but for some reason it is only adding information into two of the columns.

```
      ObservableList<MediaViewModel> mediaData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void initialize()
{
    ObservableList<String> formatList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("DVD", "Blu-Ray", "Game", "Music");
    formatBox.getItems().addAll(formatList);
    formatBox.setItems(formatList);
    ObservableList<String> locationList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Home", "iTunes", "Amazon", "Microsoft");
    locationBox.getItems().addAll(locationList);
    locationBox.setItems(locationList);
    ObservableList<Boolean> rippedList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(true, false);
    rippedBox.getItems().addAll(rippedList);
    rippedBox.setItems(rippedList);
    ObservableList<String> filterList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("DVD", "Blu-Ray", "Game", "Music");
    filterBox.getItems().addAll(filterList);
    filterBox.setItems(filterList);
    titleColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MediaViewModel, String>("title"));
    formatColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MediaViewModel, String>("format"));
    locationColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MediaViewModel, String>("location"));
    rippedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MediaViewModel, String>("ripped"));
    releaseDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MediaViewModel, String>("releaseDate"));
    purchaseDateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MediaViewModel, String>("purchaseDate"));
    ownerColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MediaViewModel, String>("owner"));
    mediaData.add(new MediaViewModel("Hello","02-4-2001", "04-31-2005","true","DVD","Me","Home"));
    mediaTable.setItems(mediaData);


}
```

and here is our mediaviewmodel class

```
    public class MediaViewModel //extends Application 
    {
    private final SimpleStringProperty title;
    private final SimpleStringProperty releaseDate;
    private final SimpleStringProperty purchaseDate;
    private final SimpleStringProperty format;
    private final SimpleStringProperty ripped;
    private final SimpleStringProperty location;
    private final SimpleStringProperty owner;
    //private final SimpleStringProperty ownerFN;
    //private final SimpleStringProperty ownerLN;
    //private final SimpleStringProperty ownerPhone;

    public MediaViewModel(String t, String rDate, String pDate, String r, String f, String o, String l) 
    {
        this.title = new SimpleStringProperty(t);
        this.releaseDate = new SimpleStringProperty(rDate);         
        this.purchaseDate = new SimpleStringProperty(pDate);
        this.format = new SimpleStringProperty(f);
        this.ripped = new SimpleStringProperty(r);
        this.location = new SimpleStringProperty(l);
        this.owner = new SimpleStringProperty(o);
    }

    public String getTitle() 
    {
        return title.get();
    }
    public void setTitle(String t) 
    {
        title.set(t);
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() 
    {
        return releaseDate.get();
    }
    public void setreleaseDate(String rDate) 
    {
        releaseDate.set(rDate);
    }

    public String getpurchaseDate()
    {
        return purchaseDate.get();
    } 
    public void setpurchaseDate(String pDate)
    {
        purchaseDate.set(pDate);
    }

    public String getformat()
    {
        return format.get();
    }
    public void setformat(String f)
    {
        format.set(f);
    }

    public String getripped()
    {
        return ripped.get();
    }
    public void setripped(String r)
    {
        ripped.set(r);  
    }

    public String getlocation()
    {
        return location.get();
    }
    public void setlocation(String l)
    {
        location.set(l);
    }

    public String getowner()
    {
        return owner.get();
    }
    public void setowner(String o)
    {
        owner.set(o);
    }
```

The only columns being initialized are the title column and the release date column on the mediatable tableview object.

Comment: In a debugger are the values sets after instatiating a new `MediaViewModel` - if so then it is the display class

Comment: I'm sorry I am confused by what you are asking. I am pretty new to java

Comment: Do you know what a debugger is?  Put a breakpoint in your constructor and see if it is being created - It looks fine, so either you are later on trashing the values or you are simply not displaying the correctly.

Comment: I don't know what a debugger is, but the rest of the controller class is completely commented out and the error still persists. If i don't add the mediaTable.add( new MediaViewModel... in the initialize constuctor, then the GUI displays perfectly fine. Are you saying I should test the MoviewViewModel constructor?